# PHP Multiple forms on same page with multiple buttons

Tags: php, mysql, post, pdo, form-submit

I'm busy coding a website for a local business that does Milkshakes. Naturally, they wanted to show their flavours on the site and have a management page where they could edit them. I have gotten the flavours to show up on the main page, but I am having a problem with the management page.

I have a database set up that contains a list of the flavours. The 3 main things that I am trying to allow them to do is edit, delete and add new entries. Currently, I am calling out each row (or each flavour and its id) as separate forms with 2 submit buttons: one to save changes, and one to remove it. 
Code is below:

for the management page:

```
<?php
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname', "user", "password");
$con -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = "SELECT * FROM FlavourShakes";
$data = $con->query($query);
$rows = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $flavour = $row['Flavour'];
    print "<form action=\"saveFlavorShakes.php\" method=\"post\"> \n
            <fieldset> \n 
                <input name=\"id\" value=\"$id\" readonly/> \n 
                <input name=\"Flavour\" value=\"$flavour\" /> \n
                <input type=\"submit\" name=\"edit\" value=\"Save\"> \n 
                <input type=\"submit\" name=\"edit\" value=\"Remove\"> \n 
            </fieldset> \n 
           </form> \n";
}
?>  

<form action="saveFlavorShakes.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="Flavour" />
        <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Add">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and on my processing page:

```
<?php
$flavour = $_POST['Flavour'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$btnType = $_POST['edit'];

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname', "user", "password");
$con -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = "";

try
{
    switch($_POST['edit']){
        case'Save':                             
            $query =    "UPDATE FlavorShakes
                        SET Flavour= :name,
                        WHERE id = :id;";
            $notice = "saveOK";
            $_POST['notice'] = $notice;
            break;
        case'Add':
            $query = "INSERT INTO FlavourShakes(Flavour) VALUES (:name);";
            $notice = "addOK";
            $_POST['notice'] = $notice;
            break;
        }
        //I know I haven't added a case for the remove button yet.


        $statement = $con->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(":id", $id);
        $statement->bindValue(":name", $flavour);

        $count = $statement->execute(); 

    header('Location: EditFlavorShakes.php');   
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    if ($btnType = "save"){ 
        $notice = "saveBad";
        $error = $e->getMessage();  
        $_POST['notice'] = $notice;
        $_POST['error'] = $error;
    } elseif($btnType = "delete"){ 
        $notice = "delBad";
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        $_POST['notice'] = $notice;
        $_POST['error'] = $error;           
    }elseif($btnType = "add"){ 
        $notice = "addBad";
        $error = $e->getMessage();  
        $_POST['notice'] = $notice;
        $_POST['error'] = $error;   
    }else{
        $notice = "otherBad";
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        $_POST['notice'] = $notice;
        $_POST['error'] = $error;   
    }
    echo $notice;
    echo $e->getMessage();

    //header('Location: EditFlavorShakes.php');
}
?>
```

Currently, I don't have any entries in the database. However, when I try to add Chocolate and click the Add button, I get this error:

> saveBadSQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

What I don't understand is why it `$_POST['edit']` set to save instead of add? I feel like I am overlooking some stupidly simple mistake in my code. If anyone can help me I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the right `$statement` calls into each case -

```
switch($_POST['edit']){
        case'Save':                             
            $query = "UPDATE FlavorShakes
                     SET Flavour= :name,
                     WHERE id = :id;";
            $notice = "saveOK";
            $_POST['notice'] = $notice;
            $statement = $con->prepare($query);
            // this query needs multiple values bound
            $statement->bindValue(":id", $id);
            $statement->bindValue(":name", $flavour);
            break;
        case'Add':
            $query = "INSERT INTO FlavourShakes(Flavour) VALUES (:name);";
            $notice = "addOK";
            $_POST['notice'] = $notice;
            $statement = $con->prepare($query);
            // this one needs one value bound
            $statement->bindValue(":name", $flavour);
            break;
        }
        //I know I haven't added a case for the remove button yet.


        $count = $statement->execute();
```

You're also missing several tests (you're assigning) in your if statement. Replace `=` with `==` -

```
if ($btnType == "save"){ 
        ...
    } elseif($btnType == "delete"){ 
        ...
    }elseif($btnType == "add"){ 
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
```

Comment: like i said. Stupidly simple mistake I totally looked over. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error message:

```
saveBadSQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

is because you try this line when there is no :id

```
$statement->bindValue(":id", $id);
```

And you always get saveBad cause you [assign](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) in your control:

```
if ($btnType = "save"){
```

Fix to:

```
if ($btnType === "save"){
```

Comment: yes, however it in the error message, i got it to put saveBad to indicate the save button being pressed. it should be showing addBad if there is a problem

Comment: @Termonator145 no, cause you assign instead of compare. You know = vs ===

Comment: i used a switch statement, not if/else

Comment: @Termonator145 all code except the last was copied from your examples ... it's still there in your example code.